# How to compare two columns with names and their ratings and only keep the common names with their ratings?

Tags: excel, compare, match, delete-row

I have a dataset wih four columns , column 1 contains entry names and column 2 contains ratings of these entries. Columns 3 and 4 also contain entry names and their ratings. I want to compare column 1 and 3 and only keep the common entry names and delete the ones in each column that do not appear in the other column. Thus, in the example below, "4x09-DH09", "4x09-DH035" and "4x09-DH060" and their ratings should be deleted. I found a formula in Excel that compares two columns with names and only Keeps the common names, but I don't know how to also delete the Ratings in a separate column? Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance!!!

```
name        rating      name        rating
4X09-DH03       2       4X09-DH03       2
4X09-DH09       2       4X09-DH011      2
4X09-DH011      5       4X09-DH012      5
4X09-DH035      2       4X09-DH055      2
4X09-DH055      2       4X09-DH060      2
```

Comment: Why is 4X09-DH012 and its rating being kept?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. It should not beeing kept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the first *name* is in A1, put this formula in E2,

`=COUNTIF(C:C, A2)`

Fill down as necessary. Select A1 then choose Data ► Sort & Filter ► Filter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and filter column E for *0* (*zero*). Clear the values from all of the visible cells in columns A and B and remove the filter.

Change the formula in E2 to,

`=COUNTIF(A:A, C2)`

Fill down as necessary. Select A1 then choose Data ► Sort & Filter ► Filter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and filter column E for *0* (*zero*). Clear the values from all of the visible cells in columns C and D and remove the filter.

Select columns A & B then Data ► Sort & Filter ► Sort the data on column A. If asked to expand the selection, do not expand the selection.

Select columns C & D then Data ► Sort & Filter ► Sort the data on column A. If asked to expand the selection, do not expand the selection.

You should end up with something like the following.

[image: fiddle faddle]

While your original question regarded a *formula in Excel that compares two columns* and was not tagged with <kbd>excel-vba</kbd>, here is the macro equivalent.

```
Sub mcr_Murder_Orphans()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5) = "helper"
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells(2, 5).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).formula = "=COUNTIF(C:C, A2)"
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=0"
        .Columns("A:B").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        .AutoFilter
        .Columns("A:B").Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        .Cells(2, 5).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).formula = "=COUNTIF(A:A, C2)"
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=0"
        .Columns("C:D").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        .AutoFilter
        .Columns("C:D").Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        .Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much! It worked perfect!!! This is excactely what I was looking for!!! Thanks again for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your example is located like:

```
         A         B          C        D
1   name        rating   name       rating
2   4X09-DH03      2     4X09-DH03     2
3   4X09-DH09      2     4X09-DH011    2
4   4X09-DH011     5     4X09-DH012    5 
5   4X09-DH035     2     4X09-DH055    2
6   4X09-DH055     2     4X09-DH060    2
```

In order to replicate the first column with only the common elements, try with

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$6=A2)*1),A2,"")
```

For the ratings in column B, assuminig for example that the previous formula is in A9, use in B9

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B$1:B$6,MATCH($A9,A$1:A$6,0)),"")
```

And in C9

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$1:D$6,MATCH($A9,C$1:C$6,0)),"")
```

Get ride of the blank lines between data at the end.

Hope it works!